# Sums in math mode: how to display index under the sigma sign?

Tags: math-mode

I have a fraction with sums above and under the line. How can I convince LaTeX to write the indices of the sums *under* the sigma instead of next to it?

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \frac{\sum_{s \in S} s^2}{\sum_{p \in P} p^2}
\end{displaymath}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \frac{\sum\limits_{s \in S} s^2}{\sum\limits_{p \in P} p^2}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: Might be useful. LaTeX insists on the fact that "Limit controls must follow a math operator". BTW the `sumlimits` option could be given to the `amsmath` package on loading. That automatically affects the placement of limits when in display math, not inline math. Cfr. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/4735

Answer (score 8):

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{s \in S} s^2}{\displaystyle\sum_{p \in P} p^2}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: I think `\limits` is the better choice since it does not change the size of the summation sign.

Comment: This answer seems to work, too. Unfortunately, it's not possible to mark two answers as correct.

Comment: @Thomas: As I said, the difference between the two answers lies in the size of the summation signs, which is changed by `\displaystyle` in this case.

Comment: @Michael: It is not the `\limits` that changed the size of the sigma symbols, it was the use of `\displaystyle`. I think your first comment should be deleted for confusion reasons.

Comment: @night Read my comment again. I say that `\limits` is a better choice exactly because it does *not* change the size.