# How do you place text under the union, \bigcup?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math)

In a similar manner to how you would write summation notation, I wish to have a union operator iterate over a set.

I have tried the following: `$\bigcup_{a \in A}$`, but just subscripts `$a \in A$` to the right of the union.  How do you place text actually under the union operator?

Comment: Have you tried it in display mode? Or do you actually want it under the \bigcup while being inline?

Comment: That's perfectly normal behavior and very desirable from a typographic point of view. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math/32826#32826)

Comment: You might also try `$\underset{a \in A}{\bigcup}$`.