# Putting the integration bounds below/above the integration operator

Tags: math-mode, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math)

Yesterday I've stumbled upon an article which covered just that, but I can't find it anymore.

How can I put the integration bounds above/below the integration operator instead of the default, where they're next to the symbol and push the integration term to the right?

Comment: Do not use inline mode, but displaymath mode instead! See p.12 and following of [mathmode.pdf](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) and [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math)!

Comment: I'm using the equation environment. I wasn't aware that it didn't use display mode. Thanks!

Comment: We can hardly know what exactly you do unless you provide a minimal working example. Anyways, I believe that the limits positioning is covered in the question linked by @hakaze.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `\displaylimits` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \quad \int\displaylimits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: integrals]

See page 16 of the [amsmath package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for details (although you don't actually need amsmath for this).

Comment: Just `\limits` will also do.