# Subscript of bigcap in Beamer

Tags: beamer, subscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math)

I write `\bigcap_{0 \leq k \leq n}` in `Beamer`, the subscript `0 \leq k \leq n` is shown on the right side of the `\bigcap`. Does anyone know how to put it **under**  `\bigcap` as in a non-beamer mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `\limits` just after `\bigcap`, like

```
\bigcap\limits_{0 \leq k \leq n}
```