# Limits not showing properly when placed in a fraction

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to apply a limit law in which the limit is distributed to both the numerator and the denominator. However, the `\lim_{x\to \infty}` does not render properly when I place it in a fraction (`\frac{\lim_{x\to \infty}}{\lim_{x\to \infty}}`). The `_{x\to \infty}` part shows up next to the lim.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: See [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/5001) for a discussion of `\displaystyle` vs `\textstyle` for the placement of limits either next to or above/below math operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either

```
$\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}}$
```

or

```
$\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}}{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}}$.
```

Comment: I'd prefer the second form, but such a big fraction should go in a display: if placed inline it will completely spoil the page.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Note that using such a definition, all subsequent math content will be set using `\displaystyle` (not just the `\dfrac`. To get around this, you need to grab the arguments and contain the `\displaystyle` inside a group.