# Subscript of sum

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts

How can I make a subscript for sum in latex like the following picture:

[image]

I tried `\sum_{q_i}` but that doesn't make the result I want. It makes the following result:
[image]

Comment: Why not? (You did write this in math mode, right?)

Comment: yes in math mode. I included a pic for the result

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math/32827#32827

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for the reverse direction.

Comment: So are you trying to get the inline  math style in display math? (See Martin's answer).  If so would `\\  $\sum_{q_i} {p x r}$ \\  ` be any good?

Comment: @ChrisH Don't do that please, rather use `\textstyle` in `\[ .. \]` (or some other displayed environment).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you.  I think \textstyle (which I should have heard of, but didn't remember - I rarely use display math) is actually the answer to the original question.

Comment: to get your desired results use

\[\sum_{X_1}\]

or

$\sum\limits_{X_1}$

Answer (score 5):

That is expected; it's a matter of *inline math mode* versus *display math mode*.

Inline math is meant for small fragments inside the running text, so it is typeset in a compact way, with the subscript to the side of the sum symbol. Inline math is done with `$...$`.

Display math is meant for larger, standalone equations, and is set in a paragraph of its own. Because it has more space, the subscript can be put underneath the sum symbol. Display math is done with `\[...\]` or a whole variety of environments.

Comment: `$$ ... $$` shouldn't be used (edit: in LaTeX, that is), see e.g. [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out rightnow. If you write something like

```
  \begin{equation}
  \sum_{q_i} {p x r}
  \end{equation}
```

It should give you the result you do not want to have, but if you enter mathmode in text

```
 I want to show you this sum $\sum_{q_i} {p x r}$ blabla
```

Then you would get theresult you want to have.

Comment: \textstyle{} and \displaystyle{} will allow you to switch styles in the middle of whatever you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that, but this should solve the problem