# How do I change 'displaystyle' manually?

Tags: displaystyle

I have used the following command

```
$\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$
```

to get superscript and subscript form of the lower limit and upper limit. But it
 it looks like very bigger. I want to control this size of this displaystyle manually. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Do not do this. There is a reason why the limits do on the side when used in text-mode math, if you place them above and below they disturb the line spacing.

Comment: do not use `\displaystyle` just use `\bigoplus\limits_{..}^{..}` but don't use that in inline math:-)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math

Comment: Related: [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/5001) and associated answers.