# Integral sign inside equation array becomes too small

Tags: equations, arrays

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{good}
\int_{0}^{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{ugly}
\begin{array}{c}
\int_{0}^{1}\\
\int_{0}^{1}\\
\end{array}    
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

as the labels suggest, my problem is that these two seemingly identical uses of the integral sign compile well and not-so-well respectively.
The first yields a nice two-lines-tall integral sign, the second two annoying one-line-tall little integrals (even if I add blank lines to the array).

Is there a *real* solution to this problem?
Any help greatly appreciated :)
P

Comment: Would `\displaystyle` before the array `\int` signs help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, loading the package `palatino` will give you the "Palatino" font only in text mode, but not in math mode. To get "Palatino" in both text *and* math mode, load a package such as `mathpazo` or -- assuming you have a fairly up-to-date TeX distribution -- the packages `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`.

Second, you're getting small, i.e., inline-style, integral symbols because lines inside an `array` environment are typeset, by default, in inline-style math mode rather than in display-style math mode. If, for some reason, you *must* use an `array` environment, you can get the larger integral symbols by prefixing the instruction `\displaystyle` to `\int`, as is done on the left-hand side of equation (2) in the example below. You should probably also increase the separation between rows, e.g., by affixing [2ex] after the end of the first row of the `array`.

Two big advantages of using a `gathered` environment instead of an `array` environment for the example at hand are (i) the rows would be typeset automatically in displaymath style and (ii) you wouldn't need to provide additional extra vertical separation of the rows by hand. The result of using `gathered` instead of `array` in this manner is shown on the right-hand side of equation (2) below.

For more information on displaying operator symbols such as `\int` and `\sum` in either inline-math style or display-math style, see the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001) and the associated answers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\setlength\textwidth{2in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{good}
  \int_{0}^{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{nolongerugly}
\begin{array}{c}
  \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \\[2ex] % provide some extra vertical separation
  \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} 
\end{array}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{gathered}
  \int_{0}^{1} \\ % no need to provide extra vertical separation
  \int_{0}^{1} 
\end{gathered}    
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `gathered` instead of `array`? With `amsmath`, of course. And also `mathpazo` instead of `newpx...` (at least it's a possibility).

Comment: @egreg - I do mention `mathpazo` as a possibility in the first paragraph of my answer. I'll add `gathered` to my writeup as an alternative to `array` that doesn't require the use of `\displaystyle` (or of extra vertical spacing).

Answer (score 3):

If you  want neither to change all `\int` integral signs into `\displaystyle\int` nor to use `amsmath` package, the following solution should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}

\let\normalint\int % PS
\def\int{\displaystyle\normalint} %PS

\begin{equation}\label{good}
\int_{0}^{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{ugly}
\begin{array}{c}
\int_{0}^{1}\\
\int_{0}^{1}\\
\end{array}    
\end{equation}

And if you want small integral sign:

$\int$, $\normalint$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use *always* amsmath:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{good}
\int_{0}^{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}\label{not ugly}
\int_{0}^{1}\\
\int_{0}^{1}    
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]