# Displaystyle Package?

Tags: packages, displaystyle

I am curious to know if there is a display style package, or something that would produce the same effect. You see, I get tired of constantly having to type `\displaystyle`, and making sure that it is in every place that it should be.

Is there some package that will "automatically" display style all of math symbols?

Comment: You could issue the instruction `\everymath{\displaystyle}` in the preamble... This will insert a `\displaystyle` directive every time inline-math is initiated.

Comment: So, this will work whenever I use $$ and \[ \] ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `$$ math $$`, please use `\[ a+b \]` instead.

Comment: But doesn't \[ a+b \] always center the mathematical symbols?

Comment: For inline, `\(` and `\)`

Comment: Why are my backslashes disappearing every time I use them in a comment?

Comment: I'd rather want to know why you are writing `\displaystyle` all over in the first place? I've never come across any users who needed that.

Comment: Because it makes the math symbols very pleasing to the eyes.

Comment: Use inline math for, well, inline math (`$ math $` or `\( math \)`) or `\[ math \]` for displaymath (on its own line, unnumbered). If you want to change the appearance of displayed math, there are various options. Consult Herbert Voß' [Math mode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode).

Comment: "Because it makes the math symbols very pleasing to the eyes." Well, you might think that but I'm sure most experienced TeX users disagree. `:)`

Comment: You should hardly ever need to use `\displaystyle` if you are needing it perhaps something is wrong elsewhere in your markup.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want, you might also be interested in the `\dfrac` command from the `amsmath` package, which typesets a fraction with large numerator and denominator no matter where it is.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Note that I do *not* actually recommend you do the following. But, since you ask: You can force TeX/LaTeX to issue the directive `\displaystyle` automatically whenever you initiate inline-math mode -- via either an opening-`$` or a `\(` instruction -- by inserting the following command in your document's preamble:

```
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

Again, I do not recommend you take this route. There are excellent typographic reasons for *not* using large summation, product, and integral symbols while in inline-math mode. Likewise, it's almost invariably a bad idea to typeset display-style fraction constructs while in inline math mode.

For much more information on this matter, I suggest you take a look at the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001).

I can think of only one exception to the broad stricture against the automatic use of `\displaystyle`: In `beamer`-class documents, it is quite important *not* to let the math symbols become too small. One way of achieving this is to use `\displaystyle` throughout. Even for `beamer` documents, though, providing the instruction `\everymath{\displaystyle}` may be too much of a good thing.

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up comment by the OP: To revert back to "text style" while in inline math mode, just issue the command `\textstyle`. The following MWE illustrates the look of various math objects if `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` are in effect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\everymath{\displaystyle} % automatically use display style while in inline math mode
\begin{document}
$\sum \quad \prod \quad \int \quad \frac{abc}{xyz}$

$\textstyle\sum \quad \prod \quad \int \quad \frac{abc}{xyz}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the most part I use \displaystyle whenever I write my math symbols. But I have another question: suppose in some instance I did not want to use \displaystyle, but wanted to revert back to standard settings for one line of math symbols, is there some way I can override \everymath{\displaystyle} for that one portion of my code? Is my question clear enough?

Comment: @Mack - I've provided an addendum to my answer to address your follow-up question.

Comment: Very helpful. One question. What will happen if i include this directive in the preamble, but also include `\displaystyle` in various inline math sentences. Will it bug, or just override and enable it?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra - TeX doesn't mind if it encounters the directive `\displaystyle` if it's already in display-style math.

Comment: A follow-up comment: In case your document already happens to modify the `\everymath` macro, you should write `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}` rather than "just" `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. The former expression preserves the existing token list and "simply" adds `\displaystyle` to the end of the existing token list.