# \textstyle as default method of displaying mathematics

Tags: equations, displaystyle

This has probably been asked before (although I could not locate any information). What is (are) method(s) of setting `\textstyle` as a default way of presenting displayed mathematical formulas?

Comment: this is the opposite of what you ask: [Displaystyle Package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161260/579), but maybe the inverse will work: `\everymath{\textstyle}`.  *not tried*.

Comment: It does not seem to work. There's no error during compilation, yet the result is still <code>displaystyle</code> typesetting.

Comment: The `amsmath` environments hard code `\displaystyle` in every alignment cell. You have to say `\let\displaystyle\textstyle` in the preamble; then look at the output and remove the instruction.

Comment: Whence the advice to remove the instruction? I have tried it and it is OK for me (at first sight). The only thing that the command does not influence is displayed math in the standard LaTeX displayed environments. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to do this you need `\everydisplay{\textstyle}` to affect primitive display mode and `\let\displaystyle\textstyle` to stop any explicit switches to display style.