# Using \textstyle as default with amsmath environments?

Tags: amsmath, displaystyle

I want to use `\textstyle` as the default in my amsmath equations, while retaining `\displaystyle` as unchanged command for compatibility across documents.

Apparently, amsmath hardcodes the use of `\displaystyle` and thus in [ [\textstyle as default method of displaying mathematics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296070/textstyle-as-default-method-of-displaying-mathematics) ] it was recommended to use `\let\displaystyle\textstyle` to achieve this.

Is there any possibility to make `\textstyle` the default, *without* redefining `\displaystyle`?

Comment: If, at the referenced question, David Carlisle says you need to do that, then...you need to do that.  `\everydisplay{\textstyle}` will take care of many cases, except where `\displaystyle` has been hardcoded, as in `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `amsmath` hardcodes some environments to explicitly use `\displaystyle`, *you must redefine `\displaystyle` to be `\textstyle`* as [@DavidCarlisle said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336734/164314) in your linked post.

But, just in case you need to re-use `\displaystyle`, then issue `\let\olddisplaystyle\displaystyle` before `\let\displaystyle\textstyle` to reserve the original `\displaystyle` in `\olddisplaystyle`.