# Formula with numerator and denominator of a fraction in display mode

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

I have the following formula and I want the nominator and the denominator to appear in display style. I use `\everymath{\displaystyle}` so I don't understand why they are not in display mode. How can I make this happen? Also why doesn't \everymath{\displaystyle} do the trick? Thanks!

```
C=\frac{\iint \vec{E}\epsilon\cdot \vec{dS}}{-\int_{A}^{B}\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl}}
```

[image]

Comment: When in display math mode, the fractions have `\textstyle` in both numerator and denominator.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used `\dfrac` but I don't see any different result.

Comment: @Mico My fault, you're of course right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `\displaystyle`, the numerator and denominator are one level lower, i.e. in `\textstyle`. It seems that you are expecting a definition of the form

```
\def\ddfrac#1#2{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
```

used in place of your `\frac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\ddfrac#1#2{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}

\begin{document}

\[
C=\ddfrac{\iint \vec{E}\epsilon\cdot \vec{dS}}{-\int_{A}^{B}\vec{E}\cdot\vec{dl}}
\]

But rather (cdots removed and replaced by thinspace):

\[
C=\ddfrac{\iint \vec{E}\epsilon\, \vec{dS}}{-\int_{A}^{B}\vec{E}\,\vec{dl}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For an earlier posting that defines a macro called `\ddfrac` in much the same way as you do (though using LaTeX's `\newcommand` instead of TeX's `\def`), see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173980/5001.

Comment: @Mico Really similar, however I'd prefer a slighty wider spacing invoked by the first `\displaystyle`.

Comment: @Mico I thougt about more general usage, e.g. in array-like context. But when the math mode is just outer, there are no differences, indeed.