# Double subscript not coming with product in this formula

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, fractions

I am not able to write this in latex with the subscript p|n (maybe more than one line) under the product and above the product sign also I need something to be written( say k). Moreover it would be helpful if someone tells me how to display this formula in a neat manner. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) you can get the lower-limit form of the "subscript" to the product by specifying either `\limits` or `\displaystyle`.  but really, you should show us what you have already tried, in the form of a "minimum working example", starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Formula with numerator and denominator of a fraction in display mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194605/5764)

Comment: @Werner Actually, it is not a duplicate as adding `\displaystyle` to the denominator does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The original picture can be reproduced by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{(-1)^{\varphi(n)/2}n^{\varphi(n)}}
     {\prod_{p\mid n} p^{\varphi(n)/(p-1)}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

whereas using `\Pi` instead of `\prod` would give

[image]

which is sensibly different.

If the condition is desired to be under the product sign, the correct answer is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{(-1)^{\varphi(n)/2}\,n^{\varphi(n)}}
     {\prod\limits_{p\mid n} p^{\varphi(n)/(p-1)}}
\]
\end{document}
```

(note the thin space in the numerator and in the exponent at the denominator).

[image]

Using `\displaystyle` would give a much worse output, with a too big product sign

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{(-1)^{\varphi(n)/2}\,n^{\varphi(n)}}
     {\displaystyle\prod_{p\mid n} p^{\varphi(n)/(p-1)}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exchange \Pi for \prod\limits or \displaystyle\prod

Also, you might want to use \begin{equation} or \begin{equation*} instead of [

Comment: This is basically the same as another already extant answer; moreover, we don't know if `\Pi` was actually used instead of `\prod`.

Comment: @PaulGessler The symbol used by the OP is ***surely*** `\prod`, because `\Pi` would sit on the baseline.