# math subarray/substack environment not working

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am trying to get stacked indices using subarray/substack using the following snippet, but I am not seeing stacking beneath the `sum` symbol. This is the type of output I am expecting, [image: good output]

but this is what I am getting:

[image: bad output]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \[
          \frac{\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}\forall x \\
          \mathcal{D}(x)=\mathcal{D}_i\end{subarray}} \sum_{\substack{\forall
              y\in\Omega(x) \\
   \mathcal{D}(y)=\mathcal{D}_j}} 1}
    {\sum_{\forall x }\mathcal{D}(x)}
   \]
\end{document}
```

What should I do to get proper stacking?

Comment: So you are after output that resembles [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DXh9S.png)? Issue `\displaystyle` in the numerator and denominator of `\frac`.

Comment: @werner, thanks. wish it's possible to accept a solution in a comment too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the directive `\displaystyle` at the start of both the numerator and denominator. I would also add `\,` (thinspace) between the two main terms in the numerator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
   \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l}\forall x \\
                             \mathcal{D}(x)=\mathcal{D}_i\end{subarray}}  \, 
      \sum_{\substack{\forall y\in\Omega(x) \\ \mathcal{D}(y)=\mathcal{D}_j}} 1}
   {\displaystyle\sum_{\forall x }\mathcal{D}(x)}
\]
\end{document}
```

For more on this subject, you may want to consult the posting [Fractions with large elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173899/5001).

Comment: Or `\limits`, but perhaps in this case `\displaystyle` is better.