# How to make nested fractions bigger?

Tags: pdftex, amsmath

I have a nested fraction on the right-hand side of an equation. I use the LaTeX code as follows to produce the equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T_{ex}} = \frac{\frac{1}{T_{kin}}+\left(\frac{A_{ul}}{C_{ul}}        
\frac{T_{cmb}}{T_*}\right)\frac{1}{T_{cmb}}}{1+\frac{A_{ul}}{C_{ul}}    
\frac{T_{cmb}}{T_*}}.
\end{equation}
```

However, the fractions in the denominator and numerator of the main fraction appear too small on a regular A4 page. How can I make them larger while preserving the size of text on the left-hand side.

Comment: Use `\cfrac` (continued fraction)

Comment: You also can use `\mfrac` from the `nccmath` packade (medium-size fractions, ~ 80 % of  `\displaystyle`) for the nested fractions. Sometimes it looks better.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<sup>(I swear this must be a duplicate question, but I can't find one.)</sup>

*Read the comments below for why you might want to use a single `\displaystyle` instead of my answer below.*

Use `\cfrac`: (Also, use `\text{…}` for math elements that are interpreted as text, such as `\lim_{t\to\infty}C_{\text{Gasoline}=\infty}`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\cfrac{1}{T_{\text{ex}}} = \cfrac{\cfrac{1}{T_{\text{kin}}}+\left(\cfrac{A_{\text{ul}}}{C_{\text{ul}}}
\cfrac{T_{\text{cmb}}}{T_*}\right)\cfrac{1}{T_{\text{cmb}}}}{1+\cfrac{A_{\text{ul}}}{C_{\text{ul}}}
\cfrac{T_{\text{cmb}}}{T_*}}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found an earlier, related posting...

Comment: @Mico can you link it here ? The question may still be duped.

Comment: The earlier posting's title is [Fractions with large elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173899/5001). Personally, I think it's better to provide a `\displaystyle` declaration at the start of the numerator and denominator material than to employ a multitude of `\cfrac` directives.

Comment: @Mico Why would you say?  I would use `\cfrac`, not only because it is less typing, but because (to me) it seems much more descriptive of the actual mathematics.  Is there a disadvantage to using `\cfrac` that I'm as-of-yet ignorant of?

Comment: @Mico Also, I didn't realize the question had already been duped -- you sacrifice a bit when you use the mobile app :)  Reading the duped-answer makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Try typesetting `\cfrac{\cfrac{u+v}{x+z}}{\cfrac{\alpha+\iota}{\nu+\epsilon}}` and `\ddfrac{\frac{u+v}{x+z}}{\frac{\alpha+\iota}{\nu+\epsilon}}`,  and you'll see that `\cfrac` adds a whole lot more whitespace than `\displaystyle` does. This is because `\cfrac` also inserts `strut`, which is taller and deeper than `\mathstrut`.