# Displaystyle for "lim" (global) in tabular-environment

Tags: tables, math-mode, displaystyle

I want to use a tabular-environment and within it some math formulas (limits). But I want \lim to be in displaystyle (without using display-function each time or defining a new command).

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{enumitem}                                       
\usepackage{paralist}                                       
\usepackage{scrhack}                                        

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=4.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,includefoot]{geometry}        
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = blue, pdfborder ={0 0 0}, pdfstartview={FitH}]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[compact,explicit]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1.) \textbf{Limits}: Calculate the following limits
        \begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ p{5cm} p{5cm} p{5cm} }
        \lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) & \lim_{x \to 0} (x^2 + 3x - 4) & \lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 + 5)^3   \\
        \\
        \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x^5 - x^2 - 1 } & & \\
        & \lim_{x \to 4} \frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15} & \lim_{x \to a} A x^n 
        \end{tabular} \end{center}
\end{itemize}


\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) &= \lim_{x \to -2} (x \cdot x) + \lim_{x \to -2} (5 \cdot x) \\
    &= \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) + \left( \lim_{x \to -2} 5  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to set displaymode in tabular? Thank you

(2) Additional question, to the idea in the comments: How can I use this \everymath{\displaystyle} with align-environment? It doesnt work here:

```
\begin{center} \everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{align*} 
    \lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) &= \lim_{x \to -2} (x \cdot x) + \lim_{x \to -2} (5 \cdot x) \\
    &= \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) + \left( \lim_{x \to -2} 5  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) \\
    &= (-2) (-2) + 5 \cdot (-2) = -6 \\
    \lim_{x \to 4} \frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15} &= \frac{2 \lim_{x \to 4} x^{\frac{2}{3}}- \lim_{x \to 4} \sqrt{x} }{\lim_{x \to 4} x^2 - 15} \\
    &= \frac{2 \cdot 4^{\frac{2}{3}} - \sqrt{4}}{4^2 - \sqrt{15}} = \frac{2 \cdot 8 - 2}{16 -15} = 14
\end{align*}
\end{center}
```

Thank you for your patience :)

(3) I Mean: Even within align-environment there's displaymode only in highest hierarchy (don't know to explain this better). Within a frac (see numerator) the limit is again small. I would like to use full displaymode in specified environment within all "under-layers" (or in the hole document in all under-layers).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
    \lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) &= \lim_{x \to -2} (x \cdot x) + \lim_{x \to -2} (5 \cdot x) \\
    &= \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) + \left( \lim_{x \to -2} 5  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) \\
    &= (-2) (-2) + 5 \cdot (-2) = -6 \\
    \lim_{x \to 4} \frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15} &= \frac{2 \lim_{x \to 4} x^{\frac{2}{3}}- \lim_{x \to 4} \sqrt{x} }{\lim_{x \to 4} x^2 - 15} \\
    &= \frac{2 \cdot 4^{\frac{2}{3}} - \sqrt{4}}{4^2 - \sqrt{15}} = \frac{2 \cdot 8 - 2}{16 -15} = 14
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Within an environment, so it's not global, (e.g., inside `center` environment), `\everymath{\displaystyle}` should do.

Comment: I will try this, because later I got the same problem in align-environment. - But it doen't work...

Comment: You should consider use the `tasks` package fot this kind of job.

Answer (score 3):

Then use [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) to adjust the style for the columns you're interested in:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textbf{Limits}: Calculate the following limits
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ *{3}{>{$\displaystyle}p{5cm}<{$}} }
        \lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) & \lim_{x \to 0} (x^2 + 3x - 4) & \lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 + 5)^3 \\
        \\
        \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 - 2x -1}{x^5 - x^2 - 1 } & & \\
        & \lim_{x \to 4} \frac{2x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \sqrt{x}}{x^2 - 15} & \lim_{x \to a} A x^n
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to -2} (x^2 + 5x) &= \lim_{x \to -2} (x \cdot x) + \lim_{x \to -2} (5 \cdot x) \\
  &= \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right) + \left( \lim_{x \to -2} 5  \right) \left( \lim_{x \to -2} x  \right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Insert something *before* every entry in that column using `>{<stuff>}` and add something *after* every entry using `<{<stuff>}`.

Answer (score 3):

Now the question has changed. If  you want that `$..$` gives you displaystyle, you can add (within a scope, i.e., inside an environment, so the setting is not global)

```
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

On the other side, if you want fractions to use `\displaystyle` in both the numerator and the denominator, you can define a new command

```
\newcommand*\Dfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}
```

And use `\Dfrac`, but **don't abuse it**!

Comment: You already have `\dfrac`  and `\cfrac` in `amsmath`!

Comment: I'm sorry, but \dfrac is for `\displaystyle\frac` and on my system, it uses \displaystyle. `\textstyle\frac` is obtained with `\tfrac`. As for `\cfrac` it can be used for fractions inside fractions, e.g. for `conntinued fractions` (hence the name of the command).

Comment: @Bernard But the op doesn't want `\displaystyle\frac` but `\frac{\displaystyle`. With the first one (`\dfrac`) you get `\textstyle` inside the numerator/denominator.

Comment: I suppose ypu're alluding to fractions inside fractions then. The `\cfrac` command is done for such situations.

Comment: @Bernard But `\cfrac` still doesn't use `\displaystyle` inside numerator or denominator (it just uses it outside, and adds some `\strut` for a good output). This command `\Dfrac` *does* use `\displaystyle` in numerator/denominator, which is  what OP wants.

Comment: @Bernard - Please check out the posting [Fractions with large elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173899/5001).

Comment: I'll do it, but what do you call the result produced by this code: `
 $\dfrac{a + \cfrac{c}{d}}{e + \cfrac{f}{g + + \cfrac{h}{g}}} $`?

Comment: I see , `\dfrac, \cfrac` work only with… fractions. I confess I never met this situation.

Comment: @Bernard I don't know how you want me to *call it* :P But it gives the expected result. Now try `\dfrac{\lim_i}{\lim_i}` and the same with `\Dfrac`. Think of `\dfrac` *exactly* as `\frac` when it's called in `\[ .. \]`, and `\tfrac` as if you were calling `\frac` from `$..$`.