# How to display compound fractions with subscripts correctly?

Tags: typography

Which is the *correct* way to represent a compound fraction in an `equation` environment?
With *correct* I mean, a way so that the representation would give the same font dimension for all the numerators and denominators. Consider the following image:

[image]

I would like, for example, that `w_{VDW}` would have the same dimension as of `H_{W,VDW}`. Is this the typographically correct choice? What would you suggest?

I have tried `\sfrac` but it seemed worse.

Comment: Have you read [Fractions with large elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173899/5001)? The `\ddfrac` macro may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mico: thanks for the suggestion. I'll check it.

Comment: personally I'd let the numerator and denominator be smaller but it's your choice but Mico's answer in the referenced question should produce what you want.

Comment: @Mico: your suggestion produces the requested result. Thank you!

Comment: Without `amsmath` (and `\dfrac`), one can always use the `\displaystyle\frac{}{}` syntax.

Comment: how did you input this?  if you use `\dfrac` on the fractions in both the numerator and denominator of the right-hand side, those fractions *should* be set "full size".  this is no different from using `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mainly a question of style. I'll give you three different strategies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

First display with \verb|\frac|, in the right hand side
the fractions are smaller
\[
\frac{H_{W,WDV}}{H_{W,TDW}}=
\frac{
  \frac{\Delta_{VDW}}{w_{VDW}}
}{
  \frac{\Delta_{TDW}}{w_{TDW}}
}
\]
and second display with \verb|\dfrac|, in the right
hand side the fractions are larger
\[
\frac{H_{W,WDV}}{H_{W,TDW}}=
\frac{
  \,\dfrac{\Delta_{VDW}}{w_{VDW}\mathstrut}\,
}{
  \,\dfrac{\mathstrut \Delta_{TDW}}{w_{TDW}}\,
}
\]
Finally, a third display with the slashed form
\[
\frac{H_{W,WDV}}{H_{W,TDW}}=
\frac{
  \Delta_{VDW}/w_{VDW}
}{
  \Delta_{TDW}/w_{TDW}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And a fourth display, with the `\mfrac` (~80 % of `\displaystyle`) from `nccmath`. Picking up egreg's example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

First display with \verb|\frac|, in the right hand side
the fractions are smaller: \[
\frac{H_{W,WDV}}{H_{W,TDW}}=
\frac{
  \frac{\Delta_{VDW}}{w_{VDW}}
}{
  \frac{\Delta_{TDW}}{w_{TDW}}
}
\]
and second display with \verb|\dfrac|, in the right
hand side the fractions are larger: \[
\frac{H_{W,WDV}}{H_{W,TDW}}=
\frac{
  \,\dfrac{\Delta_{VDW}}{w_{VDW}\mathstrut}\,
}{
  \,\dfrac{\mathstrut \Delta_{TDW}}{w_{TDW}}\,
}
\]
Finally, a third display with \verb|\mfrac| in the right-hand side as a compromise: \[
\frac{H_{W,WDV}}{H_{W,TDW}}=
\frac{
  \,\mfrac{\Delta_{VDW}}{w_{VDW}\mathstrut}\,
}{
  \,\mfrac{\mathstrut \Delta_{TDW}}{w_{TDW}}\,
}
\] \end{document}
```

[image]