# fraction in latex with long items

Tags: math-mode, fractions

```
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \eta_1}= -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{\eta_1}{c}-\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}{c-\eta_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\eta_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)} $$
```

I need a big denominator and numerator.

Comment: Does this answer help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173980/103046?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the \dfrac (`displaystyle` fraction) command from `amsmath` or  `\mfrac` (`medium-sized` fraction,  ca 80% of displaystyle) (from `nccmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}


\newcommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \eta_1}= -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\dfrac{\eta_1}{c}-\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}{c-\eta_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\eta_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)} \]%

 \[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \eta_1}= -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\mfrac{\eta_1}{c}-\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}{c-\eta_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\eta_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)} \]%

  \[ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \eta_1}= -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{\eta_1}{c}-\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}{c-\eta_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\eta_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]