# Proper Maths way to write nested fractions

Tags: math-mode, fractions

My question concerns more the Maths field rather then the LaTeX one ... 
in fact it's about writing mathematical equations correctly.
I was looking for a way to be able to write a fraction nested in another fraction (at the numerator) in a larger font size.

I came across [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173980/229795) and asked myself: is this correct in mathematical terms?
I should premise that *I'm not a Math student*, so I'm not that familiar with certain formalisms.

But let's take the following MWE

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[ 
        \frac{\lvert \, x - fl^t(x) \, \rvert}{\lvert \, x \, \rvert} \, \le \, \frac{\cfrac{b^{p-t}}{2}}{b^{p-1}} 
        \,=\, \frac{b^{p-t+1-p}}{2} \,=\, \frac{b^{1-t}}{2} \,=\, \varepsilon_M
    \]
\end{document}
```

If I had to choose according to my 'personal taste', I would say that I prefer this first version over the following one.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[ 
        \frac{\lvert \, x - fl^t(x) \, \rvert}{\lvert \, x \, \rvert} \, \le \, \frac{\frac{b^{p-t}}{2}}{b^{p-1}} 
        \,=\, \frac{b^{p-t+1-p}}{2} \,=\, \frac{b^{1-t}}{2} \,=\, \varepsilon_M
    \]
\end{document}
```

And their respective outputs are these:
[image]
[image]
But is this correct?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting `\cfrac` inside `\frac` doesn't make suitable sizes at all, If you really have to nest I would use `\frac` here but I'd avoid nesting if possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

eek (cfrac)
    \[ 
        \frac{\lvert  x - fl^t(x)  \rvert}{\lvert  x  \rvert}  \le  \frac{\cfrac{b^{p-t}}{2}}{b^{p-1}} 
        = \frac{b^{p-t+1-p}}{2} = \frac{b^{1-t}}{2} = \varepsilon_M
    \]

 (frac)
    \[ 
        \frac{\lvert  x - fl^t(x)  \rvert}{\lvert  x  \rvert}  \le  \frac{\frac{b^{p-t}}{2}}{b^{p-1}} 
        = \frac{b^{p-t+1-p}}{2} = \frac{b^{1-t}}{2} = \varepsilon_M
    \]
 
(rearranged)
    \[ 
        \frac{\lvert  x - fl^t(x)  \rvert}{\lvert  x  \rvert}  \le \frac{b^{p-t}}{2b^{p-1}} 
        = \frac{b^{p-t+1-p}}{2} = \frac{b^{1-t}}{2} = \varepsilon_M
    \]
\end{document}
```