# How do I make the fraction look more presentable and not so small?

Tags: amsmath, fractions

```
\begin{align*}
\dv[2]{SA}{r} &=\frac{{\left({\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(12\pi^{2}r^{5})
-\left({\frac{2\pi^{2}r^{6}-9V^{2}}{2\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}}}\right)}
\end{align*}
```

I am using `amsmath`. Additionally, I am not sure why the word "align" comes before the equal sign but I can figure that out later. I mostly confused as to why the fraction is so small.

[image]

Comment: please provide a small complete document that shows the problem, where does the text `align*` come from in your output??? why is there no denominator to the fraction?

Comment: Did you mean to keep the main denominator blank?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fractions with large elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173899/fractions-with-large-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` in the last fraction

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{align*}
    \dv[2]{SA}{r} &=\frac{{\left({\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(12\pi^{2}r^{5})-\left({\frac{2\pi^{2}r^{6}-9V^{2}}{2\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}}}\right)}{}\\
    \dv[2]{SA}{r} &=\frac{{\left({\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(12\pi^{2}r^{5})-\left({\dfrac{2\pi^{2}r^{6}-9V^{2}}{2\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}}}\right)}{}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that using the `\mfrac` command (*medium-sized* fraction), from `nccmath` looks better. I took the opportunity to remove some unnecessary pairs of braces and replaced the  `\left( \right)` around the nested fraction with better sized  `\Bigl( \Bigr)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \diff[2]{SA}{r} &=\frac{\left(\pi^2 r^{10}+9V^2 r^4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}(12\pi^2 r^5)- \Bigl(\mfrac{2\pi^2 r^6 -9V^2} {2\sqrt{\pi^2 r^{10}+9V^2 r^4}}\Bigr)}{\text{denominator}}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted to omit the large parentheses around the `\mfrac` term, though.

Comment: @Mico: I have the same opinion, but respected the general layout of the O.P.,  just adapting the size of the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two suggestions:

- Use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` (while eliminating the unnecessary parentheses) for the second additive term in the numerator.
- Replace the repeated term `\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}` with a symbol, say, `W`.

I dare say the second expression is a bit more readable.

Either way, do please also supply the missing denominator term.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\dv[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1}\mathit{#2}}{\mathrm{d}#3^{#1}}}
\begin{document}

Set $W\equiv{(\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4})}^{1/2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\dv[2]{SA}{r} 
&=\frac{{({\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}})^{\frac{1}{2}}}(12\pi^{2}r^{5})-
%%\left({
\dfrac{2\pi^{2}r^{6}-9V^{2}}{2\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}}
%%}\right)
}{\text{(missing denominator??)}} \\[2\jot]
&= \frac{12\pi^{2}r^{5}W-(\pi^{2}r^{6}-4.5V^{2})/W%
}{\text{(missing denominator??)}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `\displaystyle`, you can do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\dv[2]{SA}{r} &=\frac{{\left({\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(12\pi^{2}r^{5})-\left({\frac{2\pi^{2}r^{6}-9V^{2}}{2\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}}}\right)}{}\\
\dv[2]{SA}{r} &=\frac{\displaystyle{\left({\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(12\pi^{2}r^{5})-\left({\frac{2\pi^{2}r^{6}-9V^{2}}{2\sqrt{\pi^{2}r^{10}+9V^{2}r^{4}}}}\right)}{}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]