# Math display help

Tags: math-mode, macros

I need help for what command I should do. I have a sentence, and in the middle of the sentence I use a math stuff then, more words. The part with math is smaller and smushed up. I do not want to begin an equation because it starts a new line. What command can I do to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is not answerable or can be answered in `\(\inf\)` ways...

Comment: Please check if your issues are addressed in the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math). If so, your new posting should be closed as a duplicate.