# How can I make the larger integration sign without using this $$...$$

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How can I make the larger integration sign without using this `$$...$$`
Since I have written that

```
$(Uu)(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(r_1)\Gamma(r_2)} \int\limits_0^x \int\limits_0^y \dfrac{F(x,y,s,t,u(s,t))}{(x-s)^{1-r_1}(y-t)^{1-r_2}}dt\;ds,$
```

but the output integration is looking small so I want to make large integration without using `$$....$$` so please help me.

Comment: Using `$$ <math> $$` is obsolete in LaTeX, but you can use `$\displaystyle <math> $`

Comment: See [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827)