# Align an aligned environment nested into split

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I want to align the lines inside an `aligned` that is nested inside a `split` with the rest of the equation.

This is an example:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \text{max:} 
      \quad & A,\\
    \text{s.t.:} 
      \quad & B,\\
            & \left.
            \begin{aligned}
            & C,\\
            & D,\\
            \end{aligned}
            \right\} \quad(\text{stuff}),\\
            & E.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image: mwe_aligned]

I would like C and D in the rendering above to be aligned with A, B, and E.
I understand that `\left.` is what creates that space, but I don't know what to replace it with (Whatever I replace it with, I get a `Missing delimiter` error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a nested `array`, so you don't really have to fiddle with the horizontal space adjustment (except for the "null delimiter" `\left.`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{r@{\quad}l}
    \text{max:}  & A, \\
    \text{s.t.:} & B, \\
                 & \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
                 \begin{array}{@{}l}
                   C, \\
                   D,
                 \end{array}\right\} \qquad \text{(stuff),} \\
                 & E.
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, this avoids the need to insert the two "\!"s, right?

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino: Yes. The use of `@{}` removes the column spacing so things line up as expected.

Comment: I also like the fact that I can stretch the space between the lines with this solution

Comment: If instead of 'A' I have some math, say a summation, this is rendered as if it was inline math (basically like if it was inside $ $, instead of $$ $$, so that we understand). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino: See [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5764); you can use `\displaystyle` to correct the behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

`\left.` inserts `\nulldelimiterspace` and you need two `\!`s

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \text{max:}
      \quad & A,\\
    \text{s.t.:}
      \quad & B,\\
            & \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
            \!\!\begin{aligned}
            & C,\\
            & D,\\
            \end{aligned}
            \right\} \quad(\text{stuff}),\\
            & E.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the two `\!'s? Does that depend on the fact I use aligned?

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino With `aligned`, sometimes it becomes necessary to use `\!`. For details on `\!`, read [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354)

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions, both using the `rcases` environment, from `mathtools`. The second solution replaces the `split` environment with `alignedat`; it allows to typeset the `\quad`only once.

```
     \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \text{max:}
      \quad & A,\\
    \text{s.t.:}
      \quad & B,\\
            & \mkern-6mu
            \begin{rcases}
            C,\\
            D,\\
            \end{rcases}
            \quad(\text{stuff}),\\
            & E.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    \text{max:}
      & \quad && A, \\
    \text{s.t.:}
       & & &B, \\
  & & &\mkern-6mu
 \begin{rcases}
 C,\\
 D,\\
 \end{rcases}
 \quad(\text{stuff}), \\
             & && E.
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]