# Getting a fraction in the middle of the sentence

Tags: fractions

I am trying to enter a sentence that contains a fraction in between it using Latex.

My code looks like this:

```
Which of the following fractions is smaller than $\frac{1}{5}$
```

It looks like this:

[image].

How do I change the equation so that it looks more aligned with the text? I want the text to be like this:

[image]

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Please have a look at [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824)

Comment: I think that you need to post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) as for me `\frac{1}{5}` produces exactly what you want. So, I think that something in your tex file is changing the default behaviour. This said, if you are using the  [amsmath package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) then `\tfrac{1}{5}` will almost certainly work -- `\tfrac` forces the fraction to be typeset in "text" mode. There is a corresponding `\dfrac` for forcing the fraction into display mode.

Comment: @Andrew thanks first of all. I have tried \tfrac and \frac. But I want the fraction to be at the center.

Comment: Are you setting this on a website using Mathjax?

Comment: @Warner, it doesn't look like MathJax, it looks like an image.  MathJax would have centered the fraction on the math axis (even if it were using image fonts).  He may be using some other TeX plugin on a blog, perhaps one that runs TeX on the server and delivers an image (badly placed).

Answer (score 5):

In running text I tend to use something like `3/4`.

If you use the memoir class it provides a variety of ways of setting fractions.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
In memoir fractions can be typeset like 3/4 or $\frac{3}{4}$ or
\slashfrac{3}{4} or \slashfracstyle{3/4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off topic: I hope that somebody can tell me how to upload a LaTeX MWE file and also a pdf file showing the result of processing it.

Comment: Peter, MWE's are intended to be small, so just cut and paste them into the GIU. If you indent then by four spaces then code highlighting kicks in. Otherwise you can select the code block and hit the `{}` key in the GUI. To insert images use the "picture" key in the GUI. See the `?` on the top right side of the GUI or the [editing help page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `amsmath`, even, to get the default centred result. (But you do need it to switch easily to display size or whatever using e.g. `\dfrac`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Which of the following fractions is smaller than $\frac{1}{5}$?
\end{document}
```

[image: centred fraction]

In text with a standard class, I would tend to use `nicefrac` but if this is a set of examples for younger students, this style would almost certainly be inappropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\begin{document}
  Which of the following fractions is smaller than $\frac{1}{5}$?

  Which of the following fractions is smaller than \nicefrac{1}{5}?
\end{document}
```

[image: nicer fractions in text]

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments I think there is something wrong in your preamble as, for in-lined mathematics, the default behaviour of `\frac` is what you want. To demonstrate this consider the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% you need this!
\begin{document}
\textsf{frac}: Which of the following fractions is smaller than $\frac{1}{5}$ and
bigger than $\frac{3}{7}$?

\textsf{tfrac}:   Which of the following fractions is smaller than $\tfrac{1}{5}$ and
bigger than $\tfrac{3}{7}$?

\textsf{dfrac}: Which of the following fractions is smaller than $\dfrac{1}{5}$ and
bigger than $\dfrac{3}{7}$?

For displayed equations \verb|\frac| defaults to \verb|\dfrac|:
\[ \textsf{respectively, frac, tfrac and dfrac:}
         \frac{1}{5}, \tfrac{1}{5} \text{and } \dfrac{1}{5}.
\]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

As you see from the image, the fractions are centered in the text. Perhaps you are missing `\usepackage{amsmath}` or perhaps you are loading another package which redefines the default behaviour of `\frac`. Unless you give us a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) we won't be able to tell you what the problem is.