# Having sub/super scripts on the side for \sum

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

When writing `\sum_{n=1}^\infty`, the subscript and superscript will appear below and above the big Sigma symbol:
[image]

Though when writing `\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty`, they will appear on the sides:
[image]

I would like to use the `\sum` symbol, but having the sub/super script to appear on the side, just like with `\Sigma`. How do I achieve that? Due to space efficiency.

Comment: `\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n`.

Comment: See also [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827)

Comment: the `\limits` style is the default in display.  the version with limits to the side is the default in text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this by using either `\nolimits` or `\textstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Here is a sum:
\[\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{n}X_i.\]

Here is another sum:
\[{\textstyle\sum}_{i=1}^{n}X_i.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding the second option is appreciated. Thank you.