# Different ways of inserting an expression into a text

Tags: math-mode, text

I stumbled upon those two ways of writing a mathematical expression inside a text:

[image]

I could easily do the first one by writing the expression inside `$`s, but what about the second one? If I use `\begin{displaymath}`, it looks like this:

[image]

What is the correct command for this?

Comment: Your second picture shows inline math  with `\displaystyle`, which leads to inconsistent line spacing. There probably will be an answer be @egreg in a few minutes.

Comment: Related: [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827)

Answer (score 10):

Actually there's a third way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\textwidth}{.8\textwidth} % just for the example

\begin{document}

Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota 
$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ i kot
jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny.

Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota 
$e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ i kot
jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny.

Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota 
$\displaystyle e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ i kot
jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Which one to prefer? The third way is definitely to avoid, because it creates too much space between lines; also the second way has the same defect, but less evident. The first way ensures constant advancement between baselines, making for a better appearance and better readability.
Setting limits to the right, rather than above and below is a device very commonly used in mathematical typography exactly for avoiding the problem of getting bad white stripes in a page. The `\limits` trick can be handy in some cases, but should not be abused. Using `\displaystyle` is definitely the wrong way to go.

However, when a formula is rather complex, you should consider setting it in a display, which avoids the problem and makes the formula to stand out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\textwidth}{.8\textwidth} % just for the example

\begin{document}

Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota
\[
e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)^{\!n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}
\]
i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it :-) hihi

Comment: classic @egreg ;P

Answer (score 2):

`\displaystyle` switches between those two math styles, producing the effect you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. 

Ala ma kota $\displaystyle e = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ i kot jest czarny.

Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. Ala ma kota i kot jest czarny. 
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: No need for the braces, `\displaystyle` is just a switch, not a command that takes an argument. In fact, the braces makes things worse, as they prevent linebreaks from occurring.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you, I've edited my post (and learned something new today)!