# Diffrent size of a fraction

Tags: fractions

Is there someone who can explain me, why the fraction in align-mode looks bigger than the one in the math-mode? I would like to have the same size in both modes, hehe...Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} % Seitenlayout
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{math} E[\pi_{1}(s_{11}, s_{21})] = \frac{5}{6} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{6} (-1) = \frac{1}{4} \end{math}
\end{center}

\begin{align*}
E[\pi_{1}(s_{11}, s_{22})] &= \frac{5}{6} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{6} (-1) =\frac{1}{4} \\
E[\pi_{1}(s_{11}, s_{23})] &= \frac{5}{6} \left(\frac{5}{6} (0) + \frac{1}{6} (1)\right) + \frac{1}{6} (-1) = -\frac{1}{36} \
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is as a result of what TeX calls `\textstyle` (the size of inline math) and `\displaystyle` (the size of display math). You can force the style to be part of your `math` environment. However, using `\[`...`\]` instead of `\begin{center} \begin{math}` ... `\end{math} \end{center}` does the same (and better in terms of spacing).

Comment: For a single displayed equation do `\begin{equation*}<equation>\end{equation*}`, not `\begin{center}\begin{math}<equation>\end{math}\end{center}`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5764)