# How to write underneath $\bigcup$

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I try to write something like:

```
\[
\bigcup_{\gamma<\omega*2}\mathcal{T}_{\gamma}|_{\aleph _0}
\]
```

But it can not display `$\gamma<\omega*2$` underneath `\bigcup` in TeXstudio. What is the problem?

Here is the whole file in TeXstudio.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt,3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
    {decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=1.5mm,length=3mm]}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{line} = [fill=white, line width=.3pt]
    \tikzstyle{gray1} = [fill=gray!5,fill opacity=0.5]
    \tikzstyle{gray2} = [fill=gray!20,fill opacity=0.5]
    \tikzstyle{blue1} = [fill=blue!10,fill opacity=0.5]
    \tikzstyle{blue2} = [fill=blue!20,fill opacity=0.5]


    \filldraw[gray2](0, 9)--(-1.67,6.5)--(-1.33,4)--(5.33,4)--(7,9);   
    \filldraw[blue1](-3, 9)--(-1.33,4)--(-2,9);   
    \filldraw[blue2](-2, 9)--(-1.67,6.5)--(0,9);   

        \node[above] at (-1.2,8.3) {$\bigcup_{\gamma<\omega*2}\mathcal{T}_{\gamma}|_{\aleph _{0}}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \[ \bigcup_{\gamma<\omega*2}\mathcal{T}_{\gamma}|_{\aleph _0} \] \end{document}` works fine here, can you show a complete example?

Comment: @Torbjørn T, I add file and please take a look at. Thanks.

Comment: That's using inline math, in your original example you used displayed math. Add a `\displaystyle` after the opening `$`, or use `\bigcup\limits`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/ to learn more about this.

Comment: `\bigcup` is like `\sum` and uses the limits form with the subscript underneath in display math and the subscript form  in inline math. It is possible to overrulethis and force it to use the limits style but that negates most of the design of inline math so make sure you _really_ want to do that. It is probably better to use display math.