# subscript next to sum in equation environment

Tags: equations, subscripts

I have a sum with a subscript placed in an equation environment. The subscript is placed down the sum in this way:

[image]

However I want the subscript to be placed next to the sum, like this other sum:

[image]

The code for the first sum is as simple as this: `\sum_l`, so even without specifying the `\limits` parameter I encounter this problem.

How can I control this behaviour?

Comment: `\sum\nolimits_p`

Comment: Does the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001)?