# How to make the integral sign smaller?

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to make the integral sign smaller? I found that in the Display Mode the integral sign seems automatically longer. But I am in a context where smaller integral sign would be preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: You can precede it with `\textstyle`...

Comment: @frougon. Hi thanks. It worked well.

Comment: Here is an answer with some more related info: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math/32827#32827

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you prefer to have any size of the integral sign (you can choose the size that you like), it is possible to use `scalerel` package with the option `\scaleobj{<scale factor>}{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}


\begin{document}
\[
\int^{b}_{a}\frac{1}{x}\,dx, \quad 
\scaleobj{.5}{\int^{b}_{a}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx,
\quad 
\scaleobj{1.5}{\int^{b}_{a}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx,
\quad 
\scaleobj{2}{\int^{b}_{a}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx,\quad
\scaleobj{.3}{\int^{b}_{a}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you really much! This is what I was talking about I guess :).

Comment: @Megadeth I am happy for you, I am very glad to help you. Please, can you check instead Bernard's answer? Because it is better than mine for many reasons. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, easy! I was not making a comparison. I guess my comment was just a shout of joy. I appreciate every feedback in general.

Comment: @Megadeth Hi, :-) my code is very generic and although you like it and there are many positive and negative aspects. I hope you change the green v to Bernard because I think it is fairer and more correct :-)

Answer (score 9):

The `nccmath` package provides a medium-size integral sign , with the `\medint\int` command. There are also medium-sized fractions (`\mfrac`), the more general `medmath{...}` command. and `medsize` environments. You obtain formulæ with a size of ~80 % \displaystyle, avoiding the discrepancy with `\textstyle` .

The following code provides a demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{array} 
\newcommand{\Leg}[3][]{\left(\frac{#2}{#3}\right)_{#1}}

\begin{document}

Different kinds of integrals: 

    \begin{align*} 
    \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm d x}{1 + x^2} & = \frac\pi 4 %
     &\texttt{\textbackslash medint: \quad} \medint\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm d x}{1 + x^2} & = \frac\pi 4 \\[2ex]
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\ttfamily}r}
    \textbackslash medint\\ +\textbackslash mfrac\enspace\end{tabular} \quad \medint\int_{0}^{1}\mfrac{\mathrm d x}{1 + x^2} & = \mfrac\pi 4
       & \texttt{\textbackslash textstyle: }\quad\textstyle{\int_{0}^{1}}\frac{\mathrm d x}{1 + x^2} & = \frac\pi 4
    \end{align*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was a private conversation.