# How to force this summation output?

Tags: symbols

I wish to have the following:

[image: aa]

However when I use `\sum_{j=1}^k S(n,j)`, it gives me:

[image: bb]

How do I get the first rendering?  Thanks!!!

Comment: Just change `\sum_{j=1}^k S(n,j)` to `\sum\nolimits_{j=1}^k S(n,j)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show inline math as if it were display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math). The answers to this posting also show to show display math as if it were inline math.

Comment: I didn't know there are `display` vs `inline`.

Comment: There are two separate and independent aspects in play: (a) the size of the operator symbols (`\sum`, `\prod`, `\int`, etc) and (b) the placement of the upper and lower limits. In the case of `\sum`, what you've (re-)discovered is that if `\displaystyle` is in use, LaTeX (and many other typesetting systems too…) is to combine a large symbol size with placing the limits of summation above and below rather than to the side of the symbol. To override the default for the placement of the limits (but not for the size of the symbol), it's necessary to insert the directive `\nolimits` *after* `\sum`.