# How to make inline set unions with limits above and below?

Tags: math-operators, inline

The question is how to type such cups and caps:[image]

Comment: `$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{m}  G_i`i$, `$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} G_i$` ?

Comment: Answers to most such manipulations can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math-and-vice-versa/32827#32827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline equations (try to) respect line spacing, and shift under and over material to the side, make e.g. fractions smaller, ...

If you have high material, better write it into a display. Less cramped means better legibility. And *that* is what you should strive for in the first line.