# Issue with text and math expressions at the same time

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, formatting, align

As some have guessed, there was indeed a \center before the title. As shown in the picture, I changed that to \begin{center} \end{center*} and the rest of the text is now aligned!

I tried to be more explicit regarding the first issue, as explained in the new picture.

[image]

Original Post:

My two problems are shown in the picture: I want the math expressions to appear in their "normal" size (i.e. not to fit into the line), but then when I have two expressions they don't get spaced as you can see. Another issue is that that piece of text that I marked with a * should be aligned to the left but instead appears in the center. Is there any way to resolve these issues?

In align* mode, there is no issue, since it would automatically add space between those two integrals, say. However, it is painful to write the text within \text{} and then to break the lines manually.

[image: issues]

my TeXnic Center inputs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphics, setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\jot}{2mm}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

    The community is here to help you with questions about TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems.  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |P_\epsilon (t',\omega)|d\omega = |f(t')| \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\omega^2 \epsilon^2} d\omega = |f(t')|\frac{\sqrt \pi}{\epsilon}$, The community is here to help you with questions about TeX.
And, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |P_\epsilon (t',\omega)|dt' = e^{-\omega^2 \epsilon^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t')| dt'$ The community is here to help you with questions about TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems.
```

Comment: This is pretty much why inline math is sized smaller.  Is there a reason you don't want to use align* and \text?  That's what they're designed for.  And this made up example doesn't show why you wouldn't.  (Also, your made up example is missing `\begin{document}`.)  If you could also cut down the number of packages you're using, that would be helpful in diagnosing your problem.  Something is centering your text, instead of the default full-justification.

Comment: Just adding `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and processing doesn't produce the result you show.  Notice that the first and last lines are centered; that isn't the default behavior.  Please update your code to produce what you show; otherwise, it's impossible to guess what is happening to the last line.  (The problems with `\displaystyle` are pretty well covered in the other comment.)

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what you want, e.g., _they don't get spaced as you can see_ what is the spacing you want? And read others' comments first.

Comment: our screenshot strongly suggests that there's a stray `\centering` directive somewhere in the document that gave rise to the screenshot. Your sample code is but an excerpt from a longer document, right?

Comment: Thank you everyone. Please, take a look at my edited post if you can. By the way, I don't want the math expressions to appear small, which they would if I would let them fit into the line. I don't mind if the line spacings get varied because of large expressions such as integrals, however I don't want expressions very close to each other as exemplified in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I will interpret "I want the math expressions ... not to fit into the line" to mean that they should be typeset as displayed rather than as inline equations. If this interpretation is correct, you should replace the `$...$` expressions with `\[...\]` expressions. `\[` initiates an unnumbered displayed equation, and `\]` terminates it.

As some of the comments have already pointed out, the wisdom of the instruction `\everymath{\displaystyle}` is *rather questionable*. Speaking for myself, the only sensible justification for its use I can think of is in `beamer` documents. Even then, I'd think twice before I'd use it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=12mm]{geometry} % <-- rather narrow margins
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert % <-- new
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{%%amsmath, % 'mathtools' automatically loads 'amsmath'
   %%graphics, % don't load both graphicx and graphics
   setspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float} % are you sure you need this package?
\usepackage{xurl}  % for improved handling of URL strings
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%\everymath{\displaystyle} % highly questionable, except maybe in 'beamer' documents
%\setcounter{page}{1}       % that's the default
%\setlength{\jot}{2mm}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}     % that's the default

\begin{document}

The community is here to help you with questions about TeX, LaTeX 
or related typesetting systems.  
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \abs{P_\epsilon (t',\omega)}\,d\omega 
  = \abs{f(t')} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\omega^2 \epsilon^2} d\omega 
  = |f(t')|\frac{\sqrt \pi}{\epsilon}\,. 
\]    
The community is here to help you with questions about TeX.
And, 
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \abs{P_\epsilon (t',\omega)}\,dt' 
= e^{-\omega^2 \epsilon^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \abs{f(t')}\,dt'.
\] 
The community is here to help you with questions about TeX, LaTeX 
or related typesetting systems.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use `\begin{align}` with an `\intertext` line or two to align the expressions above and below the interstitial text.

Comment: @Davislor. Good suggestions. Let’s wait and see if the OP declares my interpretation is even valid. :-)

Comment: Thank you both. I have cleaned up my userpackages as suggested. What is the effect of "\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert"? I have added it along with usepackage{mathtools} but haven't noticed any change with respect to the distance between the integrals that I show in the picture. Oh, and I wouldn't like to have every math expression called in a separated line as you suggest, @Mico. That is why I'm using "displaystyle".

Comment: @dekees - If you look closely at the code in my answer, you'll find a macro called `\abs` used several times. The `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` instruction in the preamble sets up the macro.

Comment: @dekees - You seem to make an equivalence where there is none: "display style math" and "displayed equation" are *not* the same, and one does not imply the other. The former refers to the size of the letters and especially the size of operator symbols such as `\sum` and `\int`. The latter refers to the math stuff (usually, but not necessarily an equation) being placed -- or "displayed", if you prefer -- on a line by itself. Please check for yourself: running `\everymath{\displaystyle}` does *not* convert inline equations into displayed equations.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there any way to have the math expressions (not just integrals, by the way) shown in their "natural" size and still be properly spaced? Please, look at the new picture in my updated post.

Comment: @dekees - Certain symbolic operators -- `\sum`, `\int`, etc. -- deliberately come in **two sizes**: a smaller one that's suitable for inline math material, and a larger one that's suitable for displayed math material. Your term "their natural size" is thus ill-defined.

Comment: @dekees - For more information on the differences between `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` -- it is abolutely crucial to accept the fact that both inline math and displayed math can operate with `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` -- and the sizes of operator symbols, please see the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math (and vice versa)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001). (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Comment: What I gathered from that post is that the way to control the size of sums, integrals etc... is to use \displaystyle or \textstyle. But this doesn't adress my question, namely how to get the large symbols automatically spaced when they appear in two consecutive lines (as illustrated in my picture in the main post). It semes that I will have to space them manually, by calling \vspace{...} before and after. Right?

Comment: @dekees - The main issue with your code is **not** the (large) size of the integral symbols; the output would look about as bad if you omitted the ill-advised `\everymath{\displaystyle}` directive.  Rather, the main problem is the use of inline math and hence the failure to generate displayed equations to display [pun intended] the long math expressions. Please accept the fact that running `\everymath{\displaystyle}` does **not** induce TeX to switch from inline math to display math.  As I said before, "display math" is not the same as "`\displaystyle`".

Comment: @dekees - The fact that the long equations happen to occur on two separate lines does *not* -- repeat, **not** -- make them displayed equations, at least not in the TeX-specific sense of the term. I'd sauy that it's utter, though possibly happy, coincidence that the equations happen to fall on different lines.  The very fact that the lines contain text *and* math material should be a dead giveaway that you're typesetting the material using inline math, not displayed math.

Comment: Oh, ok. What you recommend me then? I mean, what would be a solution? Perhaps that everytime I want to insert an integral or sum, etc... that I do it in its proper environment? I'd want them to appear in line though... :(

Comment: @dekees - What would I recommend you do? For sure, don't use `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. Beyond that, it really depends on (a) what you're looking to get typeset -- generally, reading long and complex equations is a chore  if they're typeset inline --and (b) what you think your readers are willing to put up with in terms of idiosyncrasies and eccentricities on your part. If you're a world-famous mathematician, readers will likely put up with a lot more poor typography than if it's still a good idea for you to convince readers that it's worth their time to work through your stuff.

Comment: These are just my notes on physics. I used to write them on paper, but then changed to PDF, so it's not intended for publishing. In any case, thanks for trying to help me!