Equation renders fine in LaTeX but not in Word
I have an equation in LaTeX as follows:
\[
\sideset{}{_i}\sum \text{min} \left\{ f_{i},p_{i} \right\} =
\sideset{}{_i}\sum_{f_{i}\lt {p_{i}}}f_{i} +
\sideset{}{_i}\sum_{p_{i}\le {f_{i}}}p_{i}
\]

This equation renders exactly what I am after in LaTeX viewers, as in the image below.

However, when I insert the LaTeX code into the Microsoft Word Equation Editor, it doesn't seen to recognize the "sideset" command and I get the following.

Not sure what I have done wrong. Any assistance welcome.

Why would you think that Word would support all that LaTeX can? Also your \text{min} is wrong, use the build in \min.

You're doing nothing wrong, Word does not compile LaTeX in any sense, it can just parse and map some LaTeX syntax to it's own equation system, apparently that doesn't include \sideset. What LaTeX syntax Word can parse is not really on-topic here, but possibly \nolimits might be recognised (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32827/106162)

I believe that you are searching for TeX to Word converter, if yes, Pandoc is one of a better suggestion

Word's "latex" input string just knows a few simple commands like \alpha to make a Greek letter it has no information about any commands that may be defined in latex and does not use latex in any part of its processing.

@DaiBowen - thanks for the comment - very helpful. Yes, I tried \nolimits. It works on the left hand summation but I haven't got it to work on the right hand summations with the 'stacked' condition. I will continue.

@daleif - I am just asking a question. No need to be dismissive. A more positive reply would have been "Word doesn't support all that LaTeX can". Build up not push down (end of Public Service announcement)

@DavidCarlisle - thanks for the comment. That is good to know.
