# Summation subscript under summation symbol (\limits not working)

Tags: equations, subscripts

I am trying to get the subscript in both summations in the following equation centered under the summation symbol:
[image: summation_indices_not_centered]

```
\displaystyle \Phi(H) = \min { \sum_{\substack{i \in S \\ j \notin S}} w_{ij}  \over {\sum_{\substack{i \in S}} \pi_i} }
```

I have reached the above syntax result, which compiles without error but doesn't output what I am looking for, by following the links below:

[Sums in math mode: how to display index under the sigma sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/sums-in-math-mode-how-to-display-index-under-the-sigma-sign)

[Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines)

`\limits` doesn't seem to work, i.e the expression:

```
\[ \displaystyle \Phi(H) = \min { \sum_{\limits{\substack{i \in S \\ j \notin S}}} w_{ij}  \over {\sum_{\limits{i \in S}} \pi_i} } \]
```

gives the following error message: Limit controls must follow a math operator

If possible, I would like this to work for both inline and displayed formulas

Comment: don't use `$$` or `\over` in latex, both are tex primitives which are somewhat hard to disable but should never be used in latex documents.

Comment: but as the message says `\limits` has to follow an operator so `\sum\limits_{...}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Usage of \frac instead of \over noted. How should I change the above for the equation to render correctly? I only wrote the $$...$$ after reading this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: to show the equation use an image as in the accepted answer, we do not have mathjax running on this site, it would be confusing as it doesn't use tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `\displaystyle` in front of the `\sum`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Phi(H) = \min \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{i \in S \\ j \notin S}} w_{ij}}
                      {\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{i \in S}} \pi_i}
\]
\end{document}
```

I recommend to put the sums into one line:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Phi(H) = \min \bigg(\sum_{\substack{i \in S \\ j \notin S}} w_{ij} \Big/
                       \sum_{\substack{i \in S}} \pi_i\bigg)    
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly `\Big/` would be better in the second case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please elaborate on why \limits is not needed in this case? But looks like it is when writing it inline..

Comment: @egreg Not just possibly ... thanks, modified.

Comment: @aristeidis When you use `\[...\]`, then you are in `\displaystyle`, and the large prefix operators like sum and product put the limits above and below by default. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119328/110998

Answer (score 1):

hm, limits works if they are in correct place (immediately after `\sum`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Phi(H) = \min \frac{\sum\limits_{\substack{i \in S \\ j \notin S}} w_{ij}}
                      {\sum\limits_{\substack{i \in S}} \pi_i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will use a compact mode to denote the `sum` into the `\min` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
Let be $W=\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{i \in S \\ j \notin S}}{w_{ij}}$ and $T=\displaystyle\sum_{ i \in S}{\pi_{i}}$ we have:
\[
  \Phi(H) = \min \frac{W}{T}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]